# Can you 'agree' with something in varying degrees?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

When constructing a survey question is it correct to ask a respondent:

```
Which of the statements do you agree with more?
```

Agreement seems like it should be binary.  To agree with one thing more than another turns agreement into a sliding scale.  Is there a better way to ask the respondent's preference?

Comment: Surveys commonly ask people to rate their feelings towards various statements, asking if they *strongly agree*, *agree*, *disagree*, or *strongly disagree*. That said, you could always ask something like: "Which of the following statements best represents your viewpoint?"

Comment: Just a personal opinion, but I think the more (most?!) common wording is probably *"Which of the statements do you agree with* **most?"**

Comment: Note to explain my edit to question: I deleted the single-word-request tag and added terminology and word-usage tags.   I disagree with some premises of the question but didn't edit them, and didn't vote on the question.

Comment: jwpat - I've used some of the other SE sites quite a bit but am pretty new to this community.  I'd love any pointers on how to ask better questions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's perfectly okay to say "I agree with you up to a point" or I partly agree with you", so similarly you can agree with one statement more than another. You could agree with both statements, but one suits your own opinions better. For example: "Scotland should have more autonomy" and "Scotland should have independence". If I was a nationalist, I would probably agree with both statements, but I would certainly agree more with the second.